# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have added the most updated Selenium dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I ran 
    mvn clean install
inside the directory with my pom.xml and I have also imported the correct classes in my app class as per the Selenium documentation

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

However when i try and run my main method, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

I look in my ~/.m2/repository folder and I don't see an openqa folder but instead I see a seleniumhq folder.

Why didn't maven install the openqa folder, and why does the documentation say to import from org.openqa... when that never exist in my jar repository. I'm very confused, I just want to be able to import selenium Webdriver successfully while having it in my local repository.

Comment: You are probably doing the very same kind of mistake as the OP at https://stackoverflow.com/q/58882789/1525602, i. e. not having all the jar dependencies (including the transitive ones!) in the classpath when you run your program. So here's the crucial question: **How do you run your program?**. Because there are way too many ways of how to build your application bundle depending on how you want to run it (from an IDE, from command line, from command line using mvn exec, as a servlet on a server...).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, check properly if you have all important dependencies for your program.
Secondly, I had similar error while running maven project:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor
```

And this problem was because of inappropriate plugin, because I tested different versions of Selenium and it didn't help me.

So when I changed `maven-jar-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
 <configuration>
   <archive>
        <manifest>
             <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
             <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
             <mainClass>your_main_class</mainClass>
        </manifest>
   </archive>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

to `maven-shade-plugin` plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                 <transformers>
                    <transformer 
implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>your_main_class</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                 </transformers>
             </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The issue was gone.
The difference between plugins you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43444019/8370915).

---

In addition, sometimes we upgrade our libraries even with same method name. Due this different in version, we get *NoClassDefFoundError* or *NoSuchMethodError* at runtime when one library was not compatible with such an upgrade.

Java build tools and IDEs can also produce dependency reports that tell you which libraries depend on that JAR. Mostly, identifying and upgrading the library that depends on the older JAR resolve the issue.

---

To summarize:

- try to change versions of Selenium, if it contains all dependencies;
- try to add necessary dependencies if you don't have it;
- try to check folder of maven if it has or not what says specific error;
- try to play with plugins if nothing helps above.

Comment: Brilliant! This has fixed my issue right away. I understand what the problem was but what I didn't understand was why wouldn't mvn package all the dependencies needed at run-time in the jar. Maybe a better configuration of the jar plugin specifying what was needed would have worked anyway... I am going to try that as well

Answer (score 5):

Encountered this error in Eclipse IDE. In Eclipse go to Project properties and in Java Build Path just add selenium jars in Classpath instead of Modulepath. Then under the Project tab on the top do a Clean to remove earlier buiid and then do a Run.

Answer (score 4):

### NoClassDefFoundError

`NoClassDefFoundError` in Java occurs when **Java Virtual Machine** is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time. For example, if we have resolved a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a Class and that Class is not available during run-time then **JVM** will throw `NoClassDefFoundError`.

The error you are seeing is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

This clearly indicates that *Selenium* is trying to resolve the particular class at runtime from `org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver` which is no more available.

As you mentioned of looking into `~/.m2/repository` folder, the maven folder structure for *Selenium v3.7.1* (on Windows) is as follows :

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.7.1
```

So when you see a **`seleniumhq`** folder, it is pretty much expected.

---

### What went wrong :

From all the above mentioned points it's clear that the related *Class* or *Methods* were resolved from one source **Compile Time** which was not available during **Run Time**.

This situation occurs if there are presence of multiple sources to resolve the Classes and Methods through *JDK* / *Maven* / *Gradle*.

---

### Solution :

Here are a few steps to solve **NoClassDefFoundError** :

- While using a Build Tool e.g. *Maven* or *Gradle*, **remove** all the *External JARs* from the *Java Build Path*. **Maven** or **Gradle** will download and resolve all the required dependencies.
- If using *Selenium JARs* within a *Java Project* add only required *External JARs* within the *Java Build Path* and remove the unused one.
- While using *Maven*, either use `<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>` or `<artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>`. Avoid using both at the same time.
- Remove the unwanted other **`<dependency>`** from **`pom.xml`**
- Clean you *Project Workspace* within your IDE periodically only to build your project with required dependencies.
- Use *CCleaner* tool to wipe away the OS chores periodically.
- While you execute a *Maven Project* always do `maven clean`, `maven install` and then `maven test`.

Comment: I think the 1st part, "What is NoClassDefFoundError", of this answer is quite correct. But I'm afraid the 2nd part, "What went wrong", contains many expectations and recommendations which probably aren't to the point. Like to use `CCleaner` or to always do `maven ...` to name some... This can confuse an inexperienced Maven user, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an IDE or working from command line? In Eclipse for example you can force downloading all dependencies by right clicking on your project, going to Maven menu item and then selecting Update Project. Then check the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" checkbox.

If you are opening from command line do:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

from your project path.

Comment: The OP writes that the Maven build and compilation was OK. So there is probably no need to force Maven to re-download the artifacts (jar-s etc.) as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are selecting jar files under modulepath, you should add them under class path.

Answer (score 0):

- `org.openqa.selenium` is the package in the `selenium-api-{version}.jar` under the `seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api` folder.
- `org.openqa.selenium.firefox` is the package in the `selenium-firefox-driver-{version}.jar` under the `seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver` folder.

So there is no openqa folder, it's just the package name under the seleniumhq folder, you should have a check into these jar.

It's hard to say what caused `NoClassDefFoundError` exception without project structure and code detail. The exception is not the same as `ClassNotFoundException`. Maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756989/5374508 would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add this dependency to pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>25.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I guess this is not necessary. Because this dependency is already there, although in version 23. It is one of the transitive dependencies you can see at the [mvnrepository page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.7.1), for example. Or do you really say that using another Guava version did the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting below  error from past 2 days and what helped me was to remove all the selenium extra dependencies like selenium-support, selenium-chrome-driver etc and only keeping the below dependencies in POM file.

**Error:-**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasAuthentication

at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
```

**Dependencies in the pom file after removing all other:-**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered this issue while running selenium test in eclipse IDE.

**Navigate to following path:**

1.Properties >> Java build path >> Libraries.

2.Add all selenium jars in Classpath instead of Modulepath.

3.Apply and close modal.

4.Now go to build path and click on "Configure Build Path".

5.Now run the selenium test.