# Error in eclipse related to selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am having some trouble getting this code to work. Please keep in mind that I am very new to this.

```
package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\iftikhar\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        if (actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle)) {
            System.out.println("Pass");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at mypackage.myclass.main(myclass.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Can someone please explain this error to me and help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have geckodriver.exe installed in your specific path?

Comment: Don't know, but my guess would be that your imports are failing. Maybe for a test, just have a basic bit of code that imports some libraries that you are absolutely certain exist. I'm particularly suspicious of the FireFox import.

Comment: how do you manage your dependencies?

Comment: Check this Discussion [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w/47845104#47845104)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with Guava libraries. If you use maven to manage your dependencies, set a Guava version manually like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error stack trace says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at mypackage.myclass.main(myclass.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
```

First of all **`ClassNotFoundException`** was thrown which inturn raised **`NoClassDefFoundError`**

---

### When does **`ClassNotFoundException`** occurs :

**`java.lang.classNotFoundException`** occurs in following cases:

- When we try to load a class by using **`Class.methodName()`** method and **`.class`** file or binary of class is not available in classpath.
- When **`Classloader`** try to load a class by using **`findSystemClass()`** method.
- While using **`loadClass()`** method of class **`ClassLoader`** in Java.
- But majority of the time, **`ClassNotFoundException`** will come only when JVM tries to load a class at run-time.

### What is **`ClassNotFoundException`**

**`ClassNotFoundException`** in Java is a subclass of **`java.lang.Exception`** and occurs when **`JVM`** tries to load a particular class and doesn't finds the requested class in classpath. It is a **`Checked Exception`** and you need to provide **`Exception Handling`** explicitly while using methods which can possibly throw **`ClassNotFoundException`** either by using **`try-catch`** block or by using **`throws`** clause.

### What went wrong :

The problem statement is :

```
if (actualTitle.equals(expectedTitle))
```

If you look at the documentation of **`equals()`** method, it is defined as :

```
equals

public boolean equals(Object anObject)

  Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Overrides: 
    equals in class Object 

Parameters: 
    anObject - The object to compare this String against 

Returns: 
    true if the given object represents a String equivalent to this string, false otherwise
```

### Explaination :

In your code block you have invoked `equals()` on the `String` **`actualTitle`** which expects **an Object** as an argument. But you have provided **`expectedTitle`** as an argument which is of type **String** instead of an **an Object** which was defined as follows :

```
String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
```

### Solution:

The simple solution would be to use either of the following methods :

- **`equalsIgnoreCase`** : public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)
- **`contains`** : public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
- **`contentEquals`** : public boolean contentEquals(StringBuffer sb)