# How can I resolve could not find or load main class org.testng.Testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I am getting below error while executing testng.xml through command prompt
Error : Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

```
D:\>cd D:\Test\20July2018\test_automation\test_Framework\TestAutomation

D:\Test\20July2018\test_automation\test_Framework\TestAutomation>set projectLocation=D:\Test\20July2018\test_automation\test_Framework\TestAutomation

D:\Test\20July2018\test_automation\test_Framework\TestAutomation>cd %projectLocation%

D:\Test\20July2018\test_automation\test_Framework\TestAutomation>set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\Ivy\*

D:\Test\20July2018\test_automation\test_Framework\TestAutomation>java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\config\testrun_config.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
```

Let me know what I am making mistake.

Thanks
Prashant

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng possible duplication

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng)

Comment: i have tried above solutions but not working so I raised it again.

Comment: How is your dependecy being handled: 1.directly via download jar,  2. via maven, 3. via gradle, something else?

Comment: Can you include sample of your testng.xml file. Also check the correct syntax would be : java -cp <includeLocationsWhereYourJarsExist> org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: I am using ant/Ivy based project

Comment: Hey Anshul, I tried it but no luck

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use wildcards in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable (which you shouldn't be using anyway). Instead try specifying the classpath on the `java` command using `-cp <your classpath>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error executing testng.xml through CLI : Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149724/error-executing-testng-xml-through-cli-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-t)