# Getting an error "Unable to initialize main class org.testng.TestNG" while running TestNG 'Maven' project from command prompt

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, command-prompt

While running `Selenium` `TestNG` `maven` project from command prompt, I am getting this error:

```
Unable to initialize main class org.testng.TestNG
```

I am using command as below:

```
java -cp C:\Users\Sonali\eclipse-workspace\FacebookLoginTestNG\lib\*;C:\Users\Sonali\eclipse-workspace\FacebookLoginTestNG\src\test\java\com\mycomapny\fbauto org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

I guess running a `maven` project is tricky. As the `lib` folder is not getting created in `maven` project, I have created it manually.

How can I solve this?

Comment: did u try this one  -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng

Comment: Does this address your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149724/error-executing-testng-xml-through-cli-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-t

Comment: Yes, I have tried both the approaches however no luck yet.