# Spring Boot JUnit with Selenium ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.utils.PrefixResolver

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to run a simple test with selenium, but I am getting ClassNotFoundException when I run my test and I don't know what dependency to import to solve this issue.

I couldn't find any example that did something different from this.

I am using Java 8 and spring-boot 1.5.10.RELEASE

Can you guys please help me with this?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class VersaoControllerTest extends AbstractTest{

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        this.webDriver.get("/");
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.utils.PrefixResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.<clinit>(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:407) ~[htmlunit-2.21.jar:2.21]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.<init>(JavaScriptEngine.java:129) ~[htmlunit-2.21.jar:2.21]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.init(WebClient.java:239) ~[htmlunit-2.21.jar:2.21]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:213) ~[htmlunit-2.21.jar:2.21]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:204) ~[htmlunit-2.21.jar:2.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.web.htmlunit.LocalHostWebClient.<init>(LocalHostWebClient.java:40) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration.mockMvcWebClientBuilder(MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration.java:55) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90ad153.CGLIB$mockMvcWebClientBuilder$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90ad153$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cf4a3653.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90ad153.mockMvcWebClientBuilder(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

[ClassNotFoundException](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/classnotfoundexception-in-java-example.html) in Java is a subclass of [`java.lang.Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and occurs when *Java Virtual Machine* tries to load a particular class and doesn't finds the requested class in classpath. It is a checked Exception and explicit Exception handling methods are required to what can possibly be throwing *ClassNotFoundException* either by using `try-catch` block or by using `throws` clause.

As per the *Java Docs* [*ClassNotFoundException*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) comes in following cases:

1. When we try to load a class by using *`Class.forName()`* method and *`.class`* file or binary of class is not available in classpath.
2. When *Classloader* try to load a class by using *`findSystemClass()`* method.
3. While using *`loadClass()`* method of class *ClassLoader* in Java.

`ClassNotFoundExcepiton` can arise only when JVM tries to load a class at run-time but nothing related to compile time which is unlike [NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w/47845104#47845104). This is because till run time JVM doesn't know about this Class and it can only be done by above specified method or by employing [Reflection](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-invoke-method-by-name-in-java.html) to read the name of class from some configuration and then load the class specified on those configuration file.

---

### This usecase

The error does gives us a hint what is going wrong as follows :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.utils.PrefixResolver
```

As per the **pom.xml** you have shared clearly the **`<version>x.y.z</version>`** tag is missing. You need to change the  as follows :

- **`selenium-api`**

  ```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **`selenium-htmlunit-driver`**

  ```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
       <version>2.52.0</version>
   </dependency>
  ```

As you are using **spring-boot 1.5.10** additionally you may also require to add either of the following **`<dependency>`** :

- **`selenium-java`**

  ```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **`selenium-server`**

  ```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: I did all these configurations, but now I am getting this error: Archive for required library: 'C:/maven_repo/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.53.1/selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar' in project 'WSLocaliza' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Comment: @brazuka In my Answer I have resolved the `ClassNotFoundException` which you were facing. The new error is from the maven repository. I think `maven clean` would solve your problem. Can you accept the Answer and raise a new Question as per your new requirement please?