# Connect java project to mongodb database

Tags: java, database, mongodb, database-connection

I'm trying to connect java project to my mongodb database. But I keep recieving this error although I imported the mongodb driver to the project:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/internal/connection/ServerAddressHelper

and that's my connection code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new 
MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Etudiant");
MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection("EtudiantC");
System.out.println("connected!");
```

Comment: Which mongo driver are you using? What does your dependency look like in Gradle/Maven?

Comment: I tried different versions of drivers from 3.0.0 to 3.9.1 and my project doesn't contain any gradle file

Comment: For the sample of code provided, what is the version you are using? Later versions have slightly different syntax, for instance in 3.9.1, getting a collection looks like this:
"MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("a_collection_name");
". Can you add the full stack trace to your original query?

Answer (score 0):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` exception tells you that the class was there when the code you run was compiled, but it is missing in your application's [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) now.

The most probable explanation is that you did add the *mongodb-driver.jar* to your classpath, but forgot about adding [its transitive dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.9.1) as well. The reported missing class `ServerAddressHelper` is present inside the *mongodb-driver-core.jar*.

So how to solve this problem? Either use a dependency management system like Maven or Gradle for automatically downloading all the necessary jar-s, or you need to do this by other means (e. g. manually). It seems like you may also use the all-in-one *mongo-java-driver.jar* instead - see project's official [documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) for details (search for "Binaries" on the page).