# Error: Unable to initialize main class is seen when trying to run java program

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following program gave an error:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class demo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Create a new object driver for class Web driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Roshan_Work\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");

    }    
}
```

The error returned was:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class demo
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

Comment: so ... did you add the mandatory libraries to your path/dependencies?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w