# How to find Selenium WebDriver path in Macbook pro M1 silica chip?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting in the below code but it error in my code?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\Users\\sunethsandaruwan\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.close();
```

Come this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/devtools/HasDevTools
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code being working as expected on Mac OS machine as,

```
    public void launchBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Documents/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
  }
```