# Import statement can't find the jar even though it is in library

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, microsoft-edge

I get this message in the console when trying to run a basic program.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/edge/EdgeDriver

In the picture it clearly shows that i have the class available in my referenced libraries but it is not being picked up during execution.

[Picture of Eclipse window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww0pL.png)

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file and if yes, does deleting it fix it?

Comment: Did you try the solutions in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w#answer-65381262), this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did some test and reproduced the problem. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWH71.png).

The cause of the problem might be this: You added the jar packages to the `modulepath` instead of the `classpath`.  Just adding them to the `classpath` fixes this issue:

[image]