# Trying to launch chrome using selenium webdriver and browse but class not found

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to open a chrome browser in incognito mode and then do a few more things beyond that with selenium.

Here is the code and I am using selenium 4.8.1

```
  package com.bocc.mavenbocc;

  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

  public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "assets/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
    options.addArguments("incognito");
    
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

}

so first off I get the following:

Error: Unable to initialize main class com.bocc.mavenbocc.Application
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

So then I found that you need to define the dependencies so I placed this in the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
     <version>4.8.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

but this still results in the same error.

what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.bocc.mavenbocc.Application Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

...implies that the **Java Virtual Machine** is unable to find the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) class at runtime which was available at compile time. As an example, if the JVM have resolved a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a Class and that Class is not available during run-time then **JVM** will throw [*NoClassDefFoundError*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47845104/7429447).

---

### This usecase

The error you are seeing clearly indicates that *Selenium* is trying to resolve the particular class at runtime from `org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver` which is no more available. Possibly the related *Class* or *Methods* were resolved from one source **Compile Time** which was not available during **Run Time**.

This situation occurs if there are presence of multiple sources to resolve the Classes and Methods through *JDK* / *Maven* / *Gradle*.

---

### Solution :

Here are a few steps to solve **NoClassDefFoundError** :

- While using a Build Tool e.g. *Maven* or *Gradle*, **remove** all the *External JARs* from the *Java Build Path*. **Maven** or **Gradle** will download and resolve all the required dependencies.
- If using *Selenium JARs* within a *Java Project* add only required *External JARs* within the *Java Build Path* and remove the unused one.
- While using *Maven*, either use `<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>` or `<artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>`. Avoid using both at the same time.

  org.seleniumhq.selenium
         selenium-java
         4.8.1
- Remove the unwanted other `<dependency>` from ***pom.xml***.
- While you execute a *Maven Project* always do

  - `maven clean`
  - `maven install`
  - `maven test`.