# Maven exec works, but java -jar does not

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar, maven-jar-plugin

I have simple maven project with only one dependency. I can install it and run it command-line via [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/):

`mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="com.MyClass"`

After packaging maven generates a .jar file in my directory. With a help of [Maven JAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) I made its manifest to know my `main` method class. It looks like:

```
...
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.1
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_66
Main-Class: com.MyClass
```

Now I want to run this .jar file like regular java executable using `java` command, but after doing the following:

`java -jar myFile.jar`

it gives an error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` concerning my only dependency.

How can I make maven to add all dependencies into my executable jar file?

Comment: Something like the Maven Assembly plugin to create a fat jar? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/ and 
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: @mrblewog Thanks, will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), in order to create a jar with all its dependencies, so your pom.xml should be like the following:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>mypackage.myclass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: Thanks, will try))

Comment: It worked! I didn't even use 'addClasspath' and 'classpathPrefix'

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is using [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/):

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an
>   uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the
>   packages of some of the dependencies.

This plugin has some advantages for large project with many dependencies. This is explained here: [Difference between maven plugins ( assembly-plugins , jar-plugins , shaded-plugins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548271/difference-between-maven-plugins-assembly-plugins-jar-plugins-shaded-plugi/43444019)

In my project I use it with this configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>com.xxx.tools.imagedump.ImageDumpLauncher</mainClass>
          </transformer>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
          </transformer>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This one is right answer also, but as my case is simple one, then @Alessandro's variant is more acceptable. I give you thumb up ;)