# log file name getting picked up from dependency's log4j2.xml

Tags: maven, log4j2, rpm-maven-plugin

I have a maven project with several sub modules, e.g **ServiceModule**, **module2**, **module3**, **UIModule**. I am packaging this into two rpms, for services and ui, say services.rpm and ui.rpm

In my services submodules, I am packaging module2 and module3 too which need to be deployed on the same machine. To do this, I have added module2 and module3 as dependencies in **ServiceModule**

I see that when the logfile is generated under /CATALINA_BASE/bin/logs directory, but instead of picking up the name from log4j2.xml under ServiceModule submodule, it picks up the name from the log4j2.xml of module2 or module3 which I have added as dependency above .

Is something wrong with the way I am packaging?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using maven-assembly-plugin? Then you should use the shade-plugin instead. see: [difference-between-maven-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548271/difference-between-maven-plugins-assembly-plugins-jar-plugins-shaded-plugi)