# Creating a fat jar that is also executable with Maven

Tags: java, scala, maven

I would like to create a fat jar that is also executable using maven (pom.xml). I am aware of the plugins that allow the creation of a jar with dependencies and of a jar that contains a manifest but whenever I try to run my jar with dependencies using `java -jar target/MyApp-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I get the "Manifest not found" error, which I don't get if I try to run the "light" jar.

Here is the pom.xml of my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <scala.version.major>2.12</scala.version.major>
        <scala.version.minor>17</scala.version.minor>
        <scala.version>${scala.version.major}.${scala.version.minor}</scala.version>
    </properties>
        
    <dependencies>
        <!-- OpenCV dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0-0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- JavaCPP dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Scala library -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Fat JAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>my.package.MyApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT:** I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-runnable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven?rq=2) which helped me creating a jar with dependencies but I am not able to execute it.

**EDIT 2:** I added the full pom.xml as requested by @khmarbaise

Comment: Please post the full pom file and not only excerpts...

Comment: Done, I didn't think it was necessary

Comment: It was necessary, because now I see that you have configured the mainClass in the maven-jar-plugin instead of the maven-assembly-plugin... you can simply remove the whole configuration from the maven-jar-plugin and define only the main class in the maven-assembly-plugin... Is there a reason why you have defined `source/target` in maven-compiler-plugin (apart from very old) ... I assume you want to compile for JDK17+ (If I correctly understand)???

Comment: I created the pom.xml after some examples I saw for applications that run on my spark cluster. Originally, this was an application for spark - which runs correctly until I get some errors for exceeding memory. I am trying to check the performances of the sequential application, so probably this is something that comes from the old application. (The pom.xml file you're watching is for the sequential application that does not use spark)

Comment: Have you tried the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)?

Comment: @khmarbaise , I added the class definition in the maven-assembly-plugin and I am now able to run the application, thank you!

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl no, I haven't tried to use shade. I don't really know much about that plugin but as far as I understand it's meant for different purposes and it will result in a "heavier" jar with dependencies. Sorry if I say something that is wrong, this is what I understood from quick searches.

Comment: Do you understand how far jars work?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I hope I did. I am using fat jar because I need to bring the class dependencies along with the jar when I run it on other machines. But I read on some other question that not all the fat jars are the same. The fat jar built with the plugin I am using (maven-assembly-plugin) should only include in the jar the raw classes that my application depends on, while the maven-shade-plugin creates something a bit different by including a difference "instance of" the classes my application depends on. I hope this is correct but please, feel free to enlighten me! ^^"

Comment: @kryozen There are several approaches to how to make an executable with what the JVM can do.    The important distinction is whether all the classes are simply combined in a single jar which works but loses metainformation, or if the jars are kept which requires additional trickery - for instance unpacking the jars to the filesystem so the standard classloader can read them, or storing in an uncompressed jar or EXE file file so a custom classloader can read them inside the jar file, which is what spring boot and launch4j does.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen As you must've understood I'm quite a beginner and I am not so familiar with these tools. I had to use maven for the first time for the project I'm working on and I kind of "tried until it worked" (which I know is horribly bad). I came with the idea that I needed to compress the classes in a fat jar since I am running my application on a Spark cluster and not all the nodes could satisfy the dependencies - but I am not sure if this is an elegant solution nor if it is truly what I needed to do.
By the way, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @kryozen nothing wrong with being a beginner - we all have at one point.  But answers require understanding where the asker is. I will recommend you at one point learn a bit more about class loading because the classpath and how it works is the tar pit everyone falls in

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks, I will try to understand more about the topic and, when asking more questions, I will specify my level of knowledge :P

Comment: @kryozen Smiley duly noted.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @khmarbaise 's comment I was able to solve my issue.
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43444019) that explains the difference between Maven plugins used to create jars.

The plugin I was using to create an executable jar previously, i.e. maven-jar-plugin, only makes the "simple" jar executable and not all the jars produced after compiling my project. To solve my issue:

1. I **removed** the maven-jar-plugin;
2. I **configured the main class** in the maven-assembly-plugin so that the fat jar created was also executable;
3. I **compiled** again the project using `mvn clean package`.

The plugin in the pom.xml looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>my.package.MyApp</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```