# Maven Java integration

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

Here's a [simple Java code with SL4J](https://bitbucket.org/krishnansriramrama/simplemavensl4j) built with maven. Following commands have no issues. All of them work well
mvn compile
mvn package
mvn clean install
mvn exec:java

But when I try any of the following

```
java -cp target/MaventestApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.maven.helloworld.App
jar tf ./target/MaventestApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get the following error

```
    exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at com.maven.helloworld.App.main(App.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Here is the relevant part of my `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.maven.helloworld.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.maven.helloworld.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Code for this sample is [here](https://bitbucket.org/krishnansriramrama/simplemavensl4j)

Can someone help me understand maven and execution process better? Appreciate your time.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926899/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory) help

Comment: Well `jar tf ...` won't execute anything, and shouldn't cause an error, either. You either need a fat jar or a manifest file. You may want to take a step back and understand how the classpath works.

Comment: The plain java command has no idea what so ever about Maven so you need to tell it.  The simplest way right now is to use the `mvn exec:java` command as suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are building your JAR file (dependencies are no included in it). You could use [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) instead (see the differences between assembly and jar plugin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25351803/5078385)).

Basically, replace your current build section by the following:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.maven.helloworld.App</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then execute the generated jar-with-dependencies using the following command:

```
java -jar target/MaventestApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

See more about creating executable JARs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/5078385).

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) that should do the job. Something like

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.maven.helloworld.App
```

The actual problem is that you only add your jar to the classpath and since you do not have the sl4j-classes inside your own archive but declared them as external dependency they are simple missing (aka `NoClassDefFoundError`).

The command above links all runtime dependencies to the classpath as configured in the pom.