# How to make sure that "java" finds the all the required classes when IDE can?

Tags: java, macos, maven, build, classpath

I have a Maven project with only one dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using an IDE and it installed all the required dependencies itself. I have written a simple code that uses the classes from `net.sf.jasperreports`. To create a the package I did `mvn package` and it created the `jar`. When I try to run the `jar` as `java -jar myjar.jar`, I get an error saying `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource`

I cannot understand how to resolve this. *The IDE is able to find the classes but when invoked from command-line, it fails to find the classes.* Why is that? What should I do?

I even tried to keep the `jasperreports-6.8.0.jar` at `/Library/Java/Extensions/` but that too did not work.

Here is how the `pom.xml` looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.suhail</groupId>
    <artifactId>JasperCSVDataSource</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.suhail.main.CommandLineRunner</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>    

</project>
```

Comment: Is the class `JRDataSource` bundled in `myjar.jar,`?

Comment: This is because the libraries are not present in the compiled jar. You have to explicitly tell maven to include them in the build process. Have a look at the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) which can be used to create a *fat jar* having dependencies included. There may be different possibilities, but that's the one I use.

Comment: @deHaar I have updated the question with `pom.xml`. Could you tell how could I use the `shade plugin`?

Comment: @J_D I never mentioned it explicitly. Could you suggest a way on how I can?

Comment: Please try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven) link

Comment: If you do not want to assemble the dependencies yourself put keep the JARs separate: With Eclipse you could use the button in the run configuration which allows you to export the java commandline with all Requisites added as class and module path.

Answer (score 0):

This is the part that uses the maven shade plugin in my project, which is of course totally different from yours:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>org.apache.poi:poi</include>
                        <include>org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml</include>
                        <include>org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas</include>
                        <include>org.apache.commons:commons-collections4</include>
                        <include>org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans</include>
                        <include>org.apache.commons:commons-compress</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <!-- Exclude main jar to avoid error 'Failed to create shaded artifact, 
                            project main artifact does not exist' -->
                        <exclude>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> Please note that this part of the `pom.xml` goes into the `<plugins> ... </plugins>` section, in my case it is below the maven compiler plugin and below the maven jar plugin. You can explicitly include certain dependencies or explicitly exclude certain ones.

The result will be 2 files in your target folder, I personally use the one that has the original name, the other one will have the original name extended by *shaded* or similar.

If you get an error stating *No main manifest attribute in ...* then change your configuration of the **maven jar plugin** as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
    </archive>
    <mainClass>com.suhail.main.CommandLineRunner</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you explain the format : `<include>org.apache.poi:poi</include>` ? Is this `<include>groupId:artifactId</include>`?

Comment: Yes, I think it is... This is basically the folder structure where the downloaded artifacts are stored as local libraries in your maven configuration.

Comment: I tried running the shaded jar produced and it gives an error saying `no main manifest attribute, in target/JasperCSVDataSource-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar`

Comment: It is already there for `maven-jar-plugin` in my pom.xml. Should I be running the shaded jar file?

Comment: Try it... I can't tell you exactly

Comment: Maybe you need the assembly plugin, too. See my edit (second plugin below shade), it is in my pom.xml as well...

Answer (score -1):

Use Maven assembly plugin instead Maven jar plugin.

see [what-are-the-differences-between-maven-jar-plugin-and-maven-assembly-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351750/what-are-the-differences-between-maven-jar-plugin-and-maven-assembly-plugin)!

Maven assembly plugin creates a fully deployable package with all dependencies packed in it.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.suhail.main.CommandLineRunner</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: It would been helpful if you could have given `pom.xml` similar to what I have posted in my question. Would help to spot things easily.

Comment: I have modified it, add above code inside <plugins> and remove old one. [See sample here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/)!

Comment: In target folder you will see two jar files now. ***JasperCSVDataSource-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar*** and ***JasperCSVDataSource-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar***.