# Spark submit ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This problem is old as Apache Spark itself, but still neither of solutions helped me.
I have following class declaration:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  ...
}
```

Class reference is org.griat.rcse.Main (ctrl+shift+alt+c in IntelliJ), the same stays in `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>org.griat.rcse</groupId>
```

The way I try to run it:

`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --class org.griat.rcse.Main Glonass112-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

And once it has worked, but caught an exception in code. After I fixed it, I `clean`ed and `package`d it. Though `pom.xml` didn't change (as well as paths and class names), it stopped submitting to Spark, showing `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.griat.rcse.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:810)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I also added `maven-jar-plugin`, not that it would help:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>org.griat.rcse.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What is the source of this black magic and how can I handle it?

Comment: Make sure the Main class is in correct directory, or you can try with other plugins like `Maven Assembly Plugin`, can you also add all maven content and your location of Main class from root directory of project ?

Comment: could you please share your complete pom.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't created a "fat jar", a jar with all needed dependencies. When you do not do this, or if some dependencies are "provided", those dependencies would otherwise need to be in the overall class path (check environment variables ending in `CLASSPATH`.

To create a fat jar, you need to use the Assembly plugin, as noted. Please see the question:

[What are the differences between Maven Jar Plugin and Maven Assembly Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351750/what-are-the-differences-between-maven-jar-plugin-and-maven-assembly-plugin)

Here is [an example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-2.2.0/pom.xml) of a pom file with the assembly plugin added.

Relevant lines:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
</plugin>
```

Here are [overall instructions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html) for the assembly plugin -- note that you may want to use a descriptor XML file, explained on the bottom of the page.

You can also easily confirm if your jar contains the class: the class should be listed when you run `jar tf path/to/assembled.jar`, [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html). You can use `grep` to make it easier: `jar tf path/to/assembled.jar|grep org.griat.rcse`

Comment: Hmm, seemes, like maven doesn't put any classes to the .jar file and it doesn't depend on this plugin. However, it seemes to be topic for another question.

Comment: By the way, manual classes compilation and then running `package` helps.

Comment: The pom file must have `maven-assembly-plugin` in it with a configuration, for the plugin to execute when `package` is run. Here is [another example](https://mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/)